# Developing PhoneGap for Android - Best practice for different screen size / pixel density

Tags: android, html, mobile, android-layout, cordova

I have recently completed the development of an iPhone application in phonegap and we are now completing the Android version of the application and I was hoping to turn to the SO community for some answers in best practice for getting your app to look right across every device.  My approach was going to be to use [sencha.io](http://www.sencha.com/products/io/) for all of the images and use em/percentage based flexible layout across the app so it scales based on available screen real estate.  Is this approach fair, does anyone 
have recommendations for workflow or implementaion?

Thank you in advance,

JN

Answer (score -1):

In order for your app to look the same across all devices, use HTML5 and CSS (which you are already using with PhoneGap, correct?)

You must decide whether or not you want your android app to look like your iPhone app, or if you want it to look differently on a Android app, or if you want it look like your app regardless of platform.

Regardless of what route you take, the key to this to use well written and well formed HTML and CSS. When i say well written, i mean to not have any layout or styling depending on HTML and do all layout and styling with CSS.

From my personal experience, you are on the right track with percentage/em.

As for sencha.io, i have never heard of that. But i personally don't see what that does that you can't do with just CSS and HTML5.

Be sure to test on as many different devices as you can!

As a side note, i would recommend not using many images to help users reduce load times and data usage.

Comment: Thank you Dewseph but this is all the obvious, sencha.io is a great tool for rezing images on the fly, take a look and you will see how much it does outside of html / css.  I was looking on best practice on writing styles for one application to be used across many devices.  I think I figured out using EM/% based layout along with css3 media queries works best.

Comment: All CSS3 media queries looks like is well formed CSS and HTML. The above is really all you need to know, i know it was obvious, but thats it. The best practice is to write clear HTML that relies on CSS to look good.